# How to apply a transform on two strings to reverse result of lexicographically compare?

Tags: algorithm, lexicographic

For example, two integers a,b, if a<b, then -b<-a;
If any two strings s1,s2, if s1<s2 (lexicographically less), how to implement a function(unary operation) f so that f(s2)<f(s1) and f(s1)>f(s2) and f(s1)==f(s1)?

In python, this can be used to compare tuple of fields without defining a new class.

Comment: If you want to implement sorting, would the flag `reverse=True` get the result you want?  For example, `lst.sort(reverse=True)`

Comment: @kate-melnykova, no for example compare tuples of (str_1, str_2), on the sorted arr, need smaller str1_ at the front; if str1_ same, then compare str2_, larger str_2 at the front.

Comment: your question is not very clear. please add the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
with some input and the desired output.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, I care more about the question itself, and I think the program I met is just the reason I find this question. Should I delete the last sentence in my question so it's not ambiguous?

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
>>> def f(s):
...     tmp = [-ord(x) for x in s]
...     return tmp[::-1] 
>>> s1='abc'
>>> s2='abcd'
>>> s1<s2,f(s1)<f(s2)
(True, False)
```

Comment: It's helpful, it's also convenient to return a string if know the range of ord. And don't sort `tmp`,  otherwise f('abc') equal to f('cba').

Comment: it can't just return ```tmp```,otherwise string that length not equal will false(ex:'abc'&'abcd')

Comment: But if return tmp[::-1], then (f('aecda') < f('bcda') ) == False . It seems that it's inevasible to judge whether tmp array length are equal.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can build a manual comparison function. For the logic in the original question, see the solution below.

```
class Cmp:
    def __init__(self, obj, *args):
        self.obj = obj
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.obj == other.obj
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.obj >= other.obj # "reverse" logic


lst = ['ab', 'ac', 'aa']
lst.sort(key=Cmp)
print(lst)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/sorting.html for more explanation.